# How do I get the current context or user identity from a separate .NET application?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, forms-authentication, membership-provider

## Background

I am developing an iterative migration from a legacy ASP.NET forms app to an MVC 4 app.

This migration is happening in stages, one section at a time, so it is necessary to run both the legacy and the new MVC application simultaneously.  For some sections, the user is directed to the new application, and for sections that have yet to be migrated, the user is directed back to (or remains on) the legacy application.

On the server, the applications are structured like this:

```
LEGACY (.NET 2.0 forms app)--
                            |--Api (new MVC 4 WebAPI)
                            |--V2 (new MVC 4)
```

So a call to `foo` page on legacy is `/foo.aspx` and on V2 it's `/V2/foo`.

Everything is in C#, but please note that **the legacy app is running on .NET 2.0 and the V2 app is running on .NET 4.5**.  I am not sure if this matters, but thought it would be important to note.

## Problem

I can not successfully share the user/authentication state between applications.  Obviously, if the user logged in on the legacy app, I need to grab their auth cookie (or take similar action) on the V2 app when a V2 page is called up so that the user does not get prompted again to log in.

## What I have tried

I have set identical `authentication` and `machinekey` elements in both web.config files:

```
  <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms cookieless="UseCookies" defaultUrl="~/someUrl" loginUrl="/" path="/" protection="All" timeout="240"  enableCrossAppRedirects ="true" domain="someDomain.com" requireSSL="false"  />
  </authentication>
  <machineKey validationKey="DE78CF63226. . .788658D142AB881" decryptionKey="0B97E8BA4C4EB4B4C524. . .54E4622E14168D2D5C84461FA2" validation="SHA1" decryption="AES" />
```

I have tried this code in the Global.asax of the V2 application:

```
protected void Application_AuthenticateRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string cookieName = FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName;
    HttpCookie authCookie = Context.Request.Cookies[cookieName];

    if (authCookie == null)
    {
        return;
    }
    FormsAuthenticationTicket authTicket = null;
    try
    {
        authTicket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(authCookie.Value);
    }
    catch
    {
        return;
    }
    if (authTicket == null)
    {
        return;
    }
    string[] roles = authTicket.UserData.Split(new char[] { '|' });
    var id = new FormsIdentity(authTicket);
    var principal = new GenericPrincipal(id, roles);

    //Thread.CurrentPrincipal = principal;

    Context.User = principal;
}
```

**But I have no idea whether or not it works** because the legacy app is not in the same solution as my V2 app and therefore when I debug the V2 app, I don't have a way to log in via the Legacy app and simulate the actual user experience of hopping between legacy and V2.

I have also just tried adding this to my `HomeController` in hopes that the identical machine keys would work some magic for me:

```
 ViewBag.UserName = User.Identity.Name;
```

Obviously, I then bind `ViewBag.UserName` to an html element in the view, but this doesn't seem to work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the machineKey compatibilityMode="Framework20SP2" on the parent app.

.net 4.5 can't read auth tokens from 4.0 (or below)

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/subscriptions/index/system.web.configuration.machinekeycompatibilitymode

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2012/10/23/cryptographic-improvements-in-asp-net-4-5-pt-2.aspx

Comment: This was the one thing that actually worked for my situation!

Answer (score 2):

The signing and encryption algorithms for forms auth switched between .NET 2.0 and 4.0; so in your 4.0 config try

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseLegacyFormsAuthenticationTicketCompatibility" value="true" />
    <add key="aspnet:UseLegacyEncryption" value="true" />
    <add key="aspnet:UseLegacyMachineKeyEncryption" value="true" />
</appSettings>
```

Note that now you have a persistent auth method hitting your webapi endpoints you are vulnerable to CSRF and you will need to protect against it. Mike Wasson has a [walkthrough](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/preventing-cross-site-request-forgery-%28csrf%29-attacks) on asp.net

Comment: Thanks for this, but even after adding these elements to the web.config, I still can't access any user context.  Can you post an example of how I would retrieve the username of the logged in user?  I have tried `User.Identity.Name` but that fails.  Am I missing something?  Thanks!

Comment: You shouldn't need to do anything magical at all; the auth cookie *should* work over both apps now. By configuring your V2 app for forms auth, without a custom AuthenticateRequest it should share the cookies just fine.

So let's just ignore the webapi bits for now, and concentrate on configuring a v2 and v4 app to share. I'd suggest to setting up a skeleton, forms authed hello User first.

Answer (score 1):

What are the domains/subdomains you're using for the two apps? Cookies are not shared between domains or even subdomains (unless the cookie is set on the wildcard domain, i.e. *.mydomain.com).

For example, if the V1 app is at v1.somedomain.com and the cookie is set on v1.somedomain.com. Then V2, at v2.somedomain.com, will *not* see it. However, if you set the cookie on *.somedomain.com, then *both* apps will see the cookie.

However, if V1 is on v1domain.com and V2 is on v2domain.com, you're out of luck. There's no way to share the cookie.

Comment: Thanks.  I was actually hoping to avoid this scenario exactly by configuring the V2 app as a subfolder of the parent domain rather than a subdomain of it.  So, since it is in a subfolder, would your logic above still apply?  Thanks!

Comment: As long as they share the domain the cookie is set on, they should both be able to see it.